# h:outputScript tag and charset attribute, is it possible?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, character-encoding

First of all, I'd like to say that I've already posted this question in [another forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2217522&tstart=0), but as I haven't had any answers until now, and this is an important issue to me, I'm asking it here too.

The HTML `<script>` tag has the `charset` attribute, but I can't specify this attribute using the `<h:outputScript>` tag. I tried to use the `preRenderComponent` system event and put the attribute manually but it had no effect; the attribute wasn't rendered. Is there a way to specify the `charset` attribute, even programmatically?

Comment: Why don't you just use UTF-8 all the time as almost everyone?

Comment: @BalusC hello, BalusC. This used to work when I was using JBoss 4.2.3. I didn't specify anything in the <script> tag. But when I started using JBoss 6 and consequently JSF 2.0 and Facelets, I noticed that the accents in my language (Portuguese) were all wrong. I don't know if this has something to do with JQuery (that I'm also using now). I just noticed that when I specified iso-8859-1 for the charset in the <script> tag, the accents where displayed well, as before. If I specify UTF-8, they don't display correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Let the editor save them as UTF-8.

Comment: @BalusC How can I save as UTF-8 using Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use UTF-8 all the time. Facelets defaults to UTF-8 already. You should take care that you configure your editor/IDE to save all textbased resources as UTF-8. In Eclipse, you need to go to *Window » Preferences* and enter filter text encoding. In **all** of the filtered preferences (Workspace, JSP files, etcetera) you can select the desired encoding from a dropdown.

[image]

You might want to make minor edits (add/remove space or something) on existing files to force Eclipse to save them as UTF-8 again.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Yes, I've found a way in "Windows > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text", that's like your answer. Now the words display fine. I would not know this if you haven't pointed out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your javascript file resides within another JAR referenced by your webapp and you can't have it converted to another encoding, then you should use a filter to set a content type for that particular file. I noticed that there's no common setting for it in JSF. 
Also, I found out that it's possible to override the default renderer for `javax.faces.resource.Script` in JSF but I don't think it would be a good strategy, so if someone finds a better solution, please, post it!

```
public class SetContentEncodingFilter implements Filter {
private final Map<String, String> pathEncodingMap = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void destroy() {
    pathEncodingMap.clear();
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String requestURI = req.getRequestURI();
    if (requestURI != null && pathEncodingMap.containsKey(requestURI)) {
        String encoding = pathEncodingMap.get(requestURI);
        response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    Enumeration<String> parameterNames = config.getInitParameterNames();
    while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String path = parameterNames.nextElement();
        String encoding = config.getInitParameter(path);
        pathEncodingMap.put(config.getServletContext().getContextPath() + path, encoding);
    }
}
```

}

> Declare the filter in your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>localizedResources</filter-name>
    <filter-class>br.mpt.mp.recad.config.SetContentEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>/javax.faces.resource/jq/ui/i18n/datepicker-pt.js.xhtml</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>localizedResources</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

or if you prefer, shall you use `org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter` from Spring

There's also an OmniFaces alternative: [CharacterEncodingFilter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/CharacterEncodingFilter)