# Jsf javascript encoding issue

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsf, jsf-2

I have a button in my .xhtml page. When user mouseover that button sometooltip will be shown. Actually when user mouseover that button a text inside a span changed via javascript method. This is the button:

```
<h:commandButton id="btn" image="resources/images/mainPage/some.png"
                onmouseover="showToolTip('A');"
                onmouseout="showToolTip('B');"
                action="#{someFacade.someaction}" />
```

This is the span:

```
<span id="tooltip">Default Tooltip ü</span>
```

And this is the javascript method:

```
function showToolTip(tooltip) {
    var newToolTip = "Default Tooltip";
    switch (tooltip) {
    case 'A':
        newToolTip = "Some tooltip ü";
        break;
    case 'B':
        newToolTip = "Some tooltip b";
        break;

    document.getElementById("tooltip").innerHTML = newToolTip;
```

}

And this is how i include javascript file in my xhtml file:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="some.js"></h:outputScript>
```

And here is my problem: 'ü' is a Turkish character. On page load 'ü' is generated without problem. But when 'ü' is generated from javascript its generated as  '�'. How can i solve this?

Comment: make sure that you're saving your files in UTF-8 format.. see more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902950/houtputscript-tag-and-charset-attribute-is-it-possible

Comment: Replace `ü` with `\u00FC`. If that works then you are not saving the document that contains the JavaScript in the correct encoding.

Comment: thank you sir. Its about the encoding problem of javascript file. If you can add your comment as answer i can make it answered so for anyone have the same problem, your answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the encoding of the javascript file to UTF-8 solved the problem.